# Static Code Analysis Comments

Tags: java, static-analysis

I have scanned my code with static code analyzer and got **Unreleased Resource: Database**  error. I am closing all the db connection below is the snap shot of my code.

```
public String methodInDAO(Bean bean) throws SQLException ,Exception
{

    Session session = null;
    Connection connection = null;
    ResultSet resultSet1 = null;
    CallableStatement callableStatement = null;

    try {
         connection = dataSource.getConnection();
         callableStatement = connection.prepareCall(query);
         resultSet1 = callableStatement.execute();
        //code operations
   } finally {
        if(null != callableStatement)
            callableStatement.close();

        resultSet1 = null;
        callableStatement = null;

        if(null != connection)
            connection.close();

        if (null != session)
            session.close();

    }

    return returnOutput;
}
```

All the thrown exceptions are handled at service layer. Could anyone suggest where is datasource not released ?

Comment: What will happen if `connection.close()` throws an exception? Is that connection still open or closed?

Comment: `resultSet1 = null;` is not closing the result set. You should `resultSet1.close()` before closing the callableStatement . [ResultSet.close](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#close()) is throwing SQLException, so you should use try{}catch() blocks when closing resources, so that the initial exception is not overridden.

Comment: any exception thrown is handled at service layer, so the exception thrown in finally block are also included in the same.

Comment: i have tried closing the resultset using resultset1.close() instead of resultset1=null but still getting the same issues

Answer (score 3):

If your JDBC driver supports [JDBC 4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/index.html), you can use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

```
try (connection = dataSource.getConnection();
     callableStatement = connection.prepareCall(query)) {
  results = callableStatement.execute();
  // code operations
}
```

> The ability to use a try-with-resources statement to automatically close resources of type `Connection`, `ResultSet`, and `Statement`

was added to JDBC 4.1.

Comment: While this is a good pattern to use, note that even today many static analysis engines do not yet properly recognize the try-with-resources pattern as a valid release of the resource. But that's on them, its their bug.